# Error User-defined methods must return a value - what should my function return?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, resampling, function

I have written a function that supppose to reproject my sentinel 1 image (Resolution 10 meters) to my sentinel 2 images (20 meters). I have written the function but I am missing the return part because i'm not sure what should my function return,
I have tried

```
return image1;
```

but I couldn't even run the script because it has identified error already.

this is the function:

```
var imageNDVIproj=ee.Image(listOfImagesNDVI.get(listOfNumbersNDVI[0]));
var NDVIProjection=imageNDVIproj.projection();

var SARresample=Clipped_Speckles.map(function(image){
  for (var i in listOfNumbersSAR) {
    var image1 = ee.Image(listOfImagesSAR.get(listOfNumbersSAR[i]));
    var Reproject=image1
    .reduceResolution({reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
    })
    .reproject({crs:NDVIProjection.crs()

    })}
});
```

**My goal in this function is to create new sentine-1 image collection that will be reproject like sentinel 2**

like demonstrated here :
[https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/resample#pixel-weights-for-reduceresolution][1]

Comment: Did you try to return the image on which you applied the reproject? return Reproject